# Want to alert AJAX feedback responses from this.responseText

Tags: ajax

I have been trying to alert this so that it prints two responses

1. when there is an error or a duplicate entry and
2. when the response is ok and prints successfully

```js
var response;
try {
    response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(this.responseText);
    alert(this.responseText);
}
if (response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

I want it to alert a response both when there is a failure and when the response is successful, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out
at this stage

console.error(this.responseText);

```
alert(this.responseText);
```

i needed to insert my error message here like this

var responseText = this.responseText;

alert('Registration failure because ' + responseText );

and below 
   console.log(response);

alert ('Registration Successful');

At this stage it prints the required outcome.